# Navigation history for RCP views

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to capture all actions going on in an eclipse ViewPart of my RCP application. For example say my view has  a TableViewer and I add, delete or modify rows in the table. Here I want capture all adds, deletes and changes to enable the user to undo or redo on the click of a button or any key combinations

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: My question is how can I implement undo and redo functions for my view. Does eclipse have any inbuilt framework by which this functionality can be achieved for ViewParts

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120203/how-to-implement-undo-redo-functionality-into-eclipse-formeditor

Comment: Thanks Arye for taking time to answer. The article links provided in the answer are no longer working